# Generate a 'Busy' or 'Working' dialogue box while a loop runs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, statusbar

I'm working with MSVS2010 and am having trouble creating a status bar or status strip. I have a loop that does some things and runs some functions. It's a "while" loop. All I need to do is display some sort of form that says "busy..." or "working.." while inside of this loop. Does anyone have specific step by step instructions of how to accomplish this? I have looked at tutorials and examples online but I am not getting a clear idea of how to accomplish this. Any help on this would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Run your loop in a BackgroundWorker.

Comment: So far I had created a form that showed the current element I was on and the total number of elements that were in my loop. So the form would show something like...."Initializing 1 out of 3". And it would increment. With such a small number, you almost never see the form popup because I have it close once its exited the loop. There are some issues going on with the counts and this "ArcMap Refresh Event" that I am trying to capture. So instead of using counts, I just need a simple box to display that says working, while it is running.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a label for it.
Just add a label and name it for example `stateLabel`

Then in your code just do smth like this :

```
stateLabel.text = "Working..."; //Change the text of the Label
while(statement = true) //Your Loop
{
    //Do your work
}
stateLabel.text = "Finished work";
```

Answer (score 0):

Something simple is to use a progress bar with the 'marquee' style property, good to make user waiting on something.
So set the' marquee' property before the loop, and then you can back to default value and/or hide this progress bar after going out through the loop.
Am I enough clear or do you want some code example?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something simple like change your cursor:

```
//change cursor to wait cursors
this.ForceCursor = Cursors.Wait;

//do loop
while(true)
{//do work}

//change the cursor back to regular arrow when work is completed
this.ForceCursor = Cursors.Arrow;
```

Or, so long as you aren't doing anything with UI controls in the while loop, you could do the loop on another thread. Just put a progress bar somewhere in your window (call it myProgBar), and make it indeterminant if you do not know how long the loop will take. Here is kind of how I would do it:

```
//create instance of loading window
YourLoadWindow loadWin = new YourLoadWindow();

//Create a thread that will do our loop work.
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => 
{
//do our looping;
while (true) {//do work}

//when loop is done, we want to hide the loading window
//but we created it on a different thread, so we must use its dispatcher to do
//the work from this thread
loadWin.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { loadWin.Close(); }));

}));

//show load window
loadWin.Show();

//start doing our work
t.Start();
```

Comment: Yes, I don't intend on doing anything to the UI controls inside the loop. I have created a small form that just says "Working....". It pops up before the loop and at the end of the loop, it closes. There is a progressBar tool in the toolbox. How would I get this progress bar to update while the loop is running>?

Comment: The problem is that if you are doing a loop on the UI thread,  it must wait till your loop is done to do anything with the UI. This includes updating a progress bar. This is why you must do the loop on a different thread, so the UI thread can deal with updating things like progress bar. Multi-Threading is likely to give you the best performance. So in my example, replace myProgBar with your window that has a progress bar.